# Rails form not submitting if too many POST parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a very strange problem. I have a form which have around 150 - 160 fills(text fields and check boxes). I tried placing a `Rails.logger.info("Params: #{params[:filterrific]})` where the form would point to once submitted to see if the parameters are being displayed.

On my development machine, All the parameters showed up perfectly but when I tried submitting on my server(production environment), the form doesn't seem to be submitted as the logger does not display the parameters. I tried disabling 10 - 20 of those fields and tried again and surprisingly it works this time. I really have no idea where the problem is and would be great if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: You probably have something on the front of your rails server maybe something like a ngnix or apache.

Comment: Yeah, the app uses nginx. I have tried adding client_max_body_size 300M; to the nginx configuration file but getting the same problem.

Comment: To be able to see if the issue is from the number of params or the size, I would try with less params -- as you did -- but much more data on the text fields and see if it's empty again

Comment: I just went down to the amount of params where it is working and entered more data. It's empty/doesn't work now. Any thoughts?

Comment: So I will still investigate on the nginx part like are you sure he restarted with the correct config file -- Have you checked nginx logs?

Comment: Looking at the doc client_max_body_size  can be setted in three different contexts. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: On inspection of the nginx logs, I found that the form is being submitted as GET rather than POST and the parameters get cut off on a certain cap which explains why the params are empty in the controller. I changed the form to post method and things are solved now. One thing that puzzled me is that ain't forms are by default suppose to submit by POST method and if it's submitting through GET, isn't the URL supposed to have the parameters behind them which in my case there isn't. Because of this, I left out the possibility that the form might be submitted through GET.